# Python Regular Expression Scrabble

Tags: python, regex, string

Is there a way to specify how many times a letter can appear in the word while not specifying order i.e "I want a match with two or less z's and 1 or less u's, but in any order"?

I am having issues using python's regular expression to find words that match a scrabble 'rack' that is obtained from the command line arguments. The rack is essentially a random number of letters (e.g. python scrabble.py uzz).

The following code is close to what I am trying to implement:

```
matches = re.findall( '^[' + rack + ']{3,'+ str(len(rack)) + '}$', dictionary, re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE)
```

`[' + rack + ']` gives me my range of characters.

`{3,'+ str(len(rack)) + '}` specifies 3 to the number of characters given (all of the words are at least 3 letters long).

`^` and `$` specify that we have to match from the beginning to the end of the string.

However, when I provide `zuz`, I get the following matches `['ZUZ', 'ZZZ']`. As you can see `ZZZ` should not match as I did not provide 3 Zs.

Comment: That type of matching can't really be done using regular expressions.  Regular expressions can't keep track of state like "how many Zs have I used so far".

Comment: What is `dictionary` in your example? Is it one word?

Comment: @trincot dictionary is the sowpods word file that I read. f = open('sowpods.txt', 'rU')
  dictionary = f.read()

Comment: And as result you want a list of all those dictionary words that can be made with the rack?

Comment: @trincot Correct, e.g. 'cabk' would yield 'back' and 'cab' and the other words that are possible using the letters from the rack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this `^(?=[^z]*z?[^z]*z?[^z]*$)(?=[^u]*u?[^u]*$)\w+$`
Substitute `\b` for the anchors if you're looking for substrings.

Explanation

```
 ^                                     # BOS
 (?= [^z]* z? [^z]* z? [^z]* $ )       # Two or less z's
 (?= [^u]* u? [^u]* $ )                # One or less u's
 \w+                                   # word chars
 $                                     # EOS
```

Add `(?i)` if you need case insensitive match.

Note that you can programmatically construct the regex to find not only
the letter but the number you would allow.

The template is

not_letter =  `'[^' + <letter> + ']*';`
letter = `<letter> + '?';`
times_allowed = `'{0,' + <times> + '}';`

rx_letter = `'(?=' + not_letter + '(?:' + letter + not_letter + ')' + times_allowed;`

From coments, one that worked  `^(?=[^z]*z[^z]*z?[^z]*$)(?=[^u]*u[^u]*$)[uz]{3}$`

Explained

```
 ^                                     # BOS
 (?= [^z]* z [^z]* z? [^z]* $ )        # 1 but no more than 2 z's
 (?= [^u]* u [^u]* $ )                 # 1 but no more than 1 u's
 [uz]{3}                               # Only u or z, exactly 3 chars
 $                                     # EOS
```

Note the last form can also be programmatic.

Example

```
 ^                                     # BOS
 (?=                                   # 1 but no more than 4 z's
      [^z]* z 
      (?: [^z]* z? ){3}                     # Quantifier = 4 - 1
      [^z]* $ 
 )
 (?=                                   # 1 but no more than 3 u's
      [^u]* u 
      (?: [^u]* u? ){2}                     # Quantifier =  3 - 1
      [^u]* $ 
 )
 [uz]{9}                               # Only u or z, exactly 8 chars
 $                                     # EOS
```

Comment: So I tried the following ^(?=[^z]*z?[^z]*z?[^z]*$)(?=[^u]*u?[^u]*$)\w{3}$ in order to limit it to the size of the rack, however I am getting characters that do not match 'z' or 'u'. One such example is 'PUT'

Comment: `that do not match 'z' or 'u'` What does that mean ? The assertions don't match anything. It works .. But what do you expect to match.

Comment: Did you read this `Add (?i) if you need case insensitive match.` in my post ?

Comment: The assertions _limit_ (prohibit) matching more than 2 z's and 1 u. That's all they do. `\w+` matches any word characters _if_ it gets past the assertion(s), which is a prerequisite.

Comment: When I ran the regex you had provided above I am getting groups that contain neither 'z' or 'u'. I expect the rack 'uzz' to match the word 'zuz' but not 'put' as 'p' and 't' are not in the rack.

Comment: If you want to require only _uz_, use that instead of `\w`, i.e. `[uz]{3}`. If you want at least a z or u, then make one required in the assertion. `^(?=[^z]*z[^z]*z?[^z]*$)(?=[^u]*u[^u]*$)\w+$` or `^(?=[^z]*z[^z]*z?[^z]*$)(?=[^u]*u[^u]*$)[uz]{3}$` respectively.

Comment: So, the _form_ of the regex validates with the assertions, and matches with the allowed characters. Trust me, anything can be done like this, it's just finding out the requirements.

Comment: The second one ^(?=[^z]*z[^z]*z?[^z]*$)(?=[^u]*u[^u]*$)[uz]{3}$ gives me the functionality that I wanted. Thanks! From what I can tell the regex looks ahead for 0 to 2 z's, 0 to 1 u's, and then grabs 3 characters if they match the range [uz], correct?

Comment: Added it to post. Be sure to vote if post's solved or help you solve your problem!

Comment: I believe you have solved my problem! Thank you and unfortunately my votes will not appear until I get above 15 reputation :/

Answer (score 0):

You could find all matching dictionary words by matching with letter-sorted versions of each of the dictionary words. Then the matching is a lot easier: you then sort the letters of your rack and put `?` after each of them to make them optional in the regular expression match:

```
def get_rack_words(rack, hash):
    if rack == '':
        return []
    # convert rack to regular expression, sorting the letters
    # and making each of them optional:
    rack = '^' + '?'.join(sorted(rack)) + '?$'
    # match with hashes (sorted letters) of dictionary words
    matches = re.findall(rack, '\n'.join(hash.keys()), re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE)
    # convert hashes back to words
    words = []
    for match in matches:
        words += hash[match]
    return words

def key_dictionary(dictionary):
    hash = {}
    # create a "hash" for each word: its letters are sorted
    for word in dictionary.split('\n'):
        if re.match(r'\w+', word):
            key = ''.join(sorted(word))
            if (not key in hash):
                hash[key] = []
            hash[key].append(word)
    return hash

# one-shot hashing of the dictionary (a multiline text with one word per line)
hash = key_dictionary(dictionary)

# sample call
result = get_rack_words('batesl', hash)
print (result)
```

I loaded the first few words from https://www.wordgamedictionary.com/sowpods/download/sowpods.txt into a string for [a demo on repl.it](https://repl.it/GQx8/3).

Comment: How interesting and very readable! It had never occurred to me to sort the words and rack. May I ask what lead you to that idea?

Comment: I don't know, it just popped up :-)